# oracle sql parameter is not working in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, oracle, parameters

I Have select satament in vb.net for populating some controls and also a treeview with date value the date value of treeview is in this formate `DD MON YYYY` and also the column format to which paramter is passes is in this format .I am trying to pass the parameter in this manner

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT 'At CFO Approval ' || count(*) ||' Cheques' || ' of Rs.' ||nvl(to_char(sum(bpv_amt),'9,999,999,999'),0) CFOApp from check_data where sta_flg = 0 and bpv_date='" & TreeView1.SelectedValue & "'"
```

But I am worried this is not working in any way what may b the isuue please help

Answer (score 0):

As usual, don't use string concatenation to build a sql text.
Use always parametrized queries. Why? See [Little Bobby Tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/xkcd-sql-injection-please-explain)

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT 'At CFO Approval ' || count(*) ||' Cheques' || " & _
                  "' of Rs.' ||nvl(to_char(sum(bpv_amt),'9,999,999,999'),0) CFOApp " & _
                  "from check_data where sta_flg = 0 and bpv_date=:bpvdate"

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(":bpvdate", Convert.ToDateTime(TreeView1.SelectedValue))
```

I assume that the treeview contains valid dates

If your format is DD MMM YYYY then you could try with this conversion (note three letters months)

```
Dim d as DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(TreeView1.SelectedValue.ToString(), _
                    "dd MMM yyyy", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(":bpvdate", d)
```

If instead you have full month names then the conversion should be

```
Dim d as DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(TreeView1.SelectedValue.ToString(), _
                    "dd MMMM yyyy", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

Comment: `String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.` here is the error after your suggestion

Comment: As I have said, I assume that the treeview contains valid dates. So what is the value of SelectedValue? It is a datetime?

Comment: No I Already Wirte In my Question Format of Both is `DD MON YYYY` but error is showing

Comment: `Select to_char(BPV_DTE,'DD MON YYYY') BPV_DTE from DATE_BPV` this is populating treeview

Comment: sir what u say now what should i do

Comment: Added some variations on the date conversion, please check.

Comment: `String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.` Still this error

Comment: Can you give me an example data present in your treeview node?

Comment: For Example `23 AUG 2012` is the TreeNode Value

Comment: So AUG is August in "us-US" culture. CultureInfo.CurrentCulture should be also "us-US" to parse correctly this date. In alternative try with CultureInfo.InvariantCulture. Or `CulterInfo provider = new CultureInfo("us-US")` and pass the provider at ParseExact

Answer (score 0):

While I agree wholeheartedly with @Steve's comment about using parameterized queries, in this case I'll just suggest adding an appropriate TO_DATE call to try and get you going.  Try this:

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT 'At CFO Approval ' || count(*) || " &
                  "' Cheques' || ' of Rs.' || " &
                  "nvl(to_char(sum(bpv_amt),'9,999,999,999'),0) CFOApp " &
                  "from check_data where sta_flg = 0 and " &
                  "TRUNC(bpv_date)=TO_DATE('" & TreeView1.SelectedValue & "', 'DD MON YYYY')"
```

---

EDIT

Added TRUNC() call to date comparison.

Tested as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE CHECK_DATA
  (BPV_AMT   NUMBER,
   STA_FLG   NUMBER,
   BPV_DATE  DATE);

INSERT INTO CHECK_DATA (BPV_AMT, STA_FLG, BPV_DATE) VALUES (100, 0, SYSDATE);
INSERT INTO CHECK_DATA (BPV_AMT, STA_FLG, BPV_DATE) VALUES (200, 0, SYSDATE-1);
INSERT INTO CHECK_DATA (BPV_AMT, STA_FLG, BPV_DATE) VALUES (300, 1, SYSDATE);
INSERT INTO CHECK_DATA (BPV_AMT, STA_FLG, BPV_DATE) VALUES (200, 0, SYSDATE);
```

Now, executing the query:

```
SELECT 'At CFO Approval ' || count(*) ||
       ' Cheques' || ' of Rs.' ||
       nvl(to_char(sum(bpv_amt),'9,999,999,999'),0) CFOApp
  from check_data
  where sta_flg = 0 AND 
        TRUNC(bpv_date) = TO_DATE('29 Aug 2012', 'DD MON YYYY');
```

results in

```
At CFO Approval 2 Cheques of Rs.           300
```

Share and enjoy.

Comment: @user1583775 - I changed the query, adding a TRUNC() call for the date comparison.  Testing indicates this should work.  Give it a try.

Comment: `"SELECT 'At CFO Approval ' || count(*) ||' Cheques' || ' of Rs.' ||nvl(to_char(sum(bpv_amt),'9,999,999,999'),0) CFOApp from check_data where sta_flg = 0 and bpv_dte='23 AUG 2012'"` Sir this works but when i repalce the Date with "&  TreeView1.SelectedVlaue &" then No Data Found